# Why does the footer menu get cropped when I add the "Product we sell in our website"

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is the pic when there is no "Product we sell in our website", the footer is not cropped
[image: Not croped]

But when I add the "Product we sell in our website", here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>


<!---------- Meta HTML Starts --------->

<html>
   <head>
      <title>Website Site</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
      <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/22fa5330d1.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <style>
/********** Common CSS Starts **********/  
html, body {
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif, arial;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #242424;
  font-weight: 400;
}
html {
  -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;
  -ms-text-size-adjust:100%;
  font-size:10px;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color:transparent;
}
* {
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  outline:0;
}
img{
  border-radius: 8px;
}
/*-----section-----*/
nav{
  display: flex;
  padding: 2% 6%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
nav-img{
  width: 100px;
}
.nav-links{
  flex: 1;
  text-align: right;
}
.nav-links ul li{
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: relative;
}
.nav-links ul li a{
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 13px;
}
.nav-links ul li::after{
  content: '';
  width: 0%;
  height: 2px;
  background: #fff;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.nav-links ul li:hover::after{
  width: 100%;
}
.header{
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(4,9,30,0.7),rgba(4,9,30,0.7)),url(jennie.png);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
}
.text-box{
    width: 90%; 
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    text-align: center;
}
.text-box h1{
    font-size: 62px;
}
.text-box p{
    margin: 10px 0 40px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff;
}
.hero-btn{
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    padding: 12px 34px;
    font-size: 13px;
    background: transparent;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.hero-btn:hover{
    border: 1px solid #787eff;
    background: #787eff;
    transition: 1s;
}
.container {
  width:1150px;
  margin:0px auto;
  display:table;
}
.width-100 {
  width:100%;
  float:left;
}
.width-50 {
  width:50%;
  float:left;
}
.width-25 {
  width:25%;
  float:left;
}
.width-75 {
  width:75%;
  float:left;
}
.width-80 {
  width:80%;
  float:left;
}
.width-60 {
  width:60%;
  float:left;
}
.width-40 {
  width:40%;
  float:left;
}
.width-33 {
  width:33%;
  float:left;
}
.width-30 {
  width:30%;
  float:left;
}
.width-20 {
  width:10%;
  float:left;
}
.main-section {
  width:100%;
  float:left;
  padding-top:80px;
  padding-bottom:80px;
}
.bg-grey {
  background:#f0f3fa;
}
.heading-section {
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}
.heading-section span {
  color: #787eff;
}
.subhead-section {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
/********** Common CSS Ends **********/
/**********  Logo and Search Panel CSS Code Starts  **********/
.search-panel {
  background: #31bbf1;
  padding: 12px 0px;
}
.search-textbox {
  padding-left: 16px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 80%;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  float: left;
}
.search-button {
  height: 42px;
  width: 55px;
  border: none;
  background: white;
  float: left;
}
.search-button i {
  color: #f13f31;
}
.cart-sect {
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 8px;
}
.cart-sect li {
  float: left;
  padding: 0px 6px;
}
.cart-sect li a {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.cart-sect li i {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #ffffff;
}
/**********  Logo and Search Panel CSS Code Ends  **********/
/**********  Main Menu CSS Code Starts  **********/
.main-menu {
  list-style: none;
}
.main-menu a {
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #2b304a;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif, arial;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.main-menu li {
  float: left;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin-left: 60px;
}
/**********  Main Menu CSS Code Ends  **********/

/**********  Product-Section CSS Code Starts  **********/
.small-container{
    max-width: 1080px;
    margin: auto;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
}
.row{
  margin-top: 5%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.col-3{
    flex-basis: 30%;
    min-width: 250px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
}
.col-3 img{
    width: 90%; 
}
.col-3:hover{
    transform: translateY(-5px);
}
.title{
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto 80px;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 60px;
    color:#ffffff;
}
.categories{
    margin: 70px 0;
}
.col-3{
    flex-basis: 30%;
    min-width: 250px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
}
.col-3 img{
    width: 90%; 
}
.col-3:hover{
    transform: translateY(-5px);
}
.small-container{
    max-width: 1080px;
    margin: auto;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
}
.col-4{
    flex-basis: 25%;
    padding: 10px;
    min-width: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
}
.col-4 img{
    width: 100%;
}
.col-2{
    flex-basis: 50%;
    min-width: 300px;
}
.col-2 img{
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 5px 0;
}
.title{
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto 80px;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 60px;
    color:#000;
}
.title::after{
    content: '';
    background: #0F1035;
    width: 80px;
    height: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.offer{
    background: radial-gradient(#fff,#537EC5);
    margin-top: 80px;
    padding: 30px 0;
}
.col-2 .offer-img{
    padding: 50px;
}
/**********   Product-Section CSS Code Ends  **********/

/**********   About us   **********/
.course{
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 100px;
}
.course-col{
  flex-basis: 31%;
  background: #BBE2EC;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
  padding: 20px 12px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.course-col:hover{
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.course-col-2{
  flex-basis: 31%;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
  padding: 20px 12px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
/**********   About us Ends  **********/

/**********  Footer-Section CSS Code Starts  **********/
.footer {
  background: #232f3e;
  padding: 50px 0px;
}
.quicklink-menu {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
.quicklink-menu li a {
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 2.5;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.social-media {
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.social-media li a img {
  width: 30px;
}
.social-media li {
  float: left;
  padding: 0px 8px;
}
.quicklink-heading {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.get-in-touch {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
.get-in-touch li i {
  color: #ed372c;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.get-in-touch li {
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 2.5;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.footer-e-mail {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.footer-website {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.footer2-bacbor {
  background: #232f3e;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  border-top: 1px solid #898989;
}
.footer2-content {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
/**********   Footer-Section CSS Code Ends  **********/
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>

<!---------- Meta HTML Ends --------->



<!---------- Logo and Search Panel HTML Code Starts --------->

<section class="header">
  <nav>
    <a href="Comp QA.html"><img src="logo.png" width="60px"></a>
    <div class="nav-links" id="navLinks">
        <i class="fa fa-xmark" onclick="hidemenu()"></i>
        <ul> 
            <li><a href="E:\COMP QA\home.html" target="_blank">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="" target="_blank">STORE</a></li>
            <li><a href="" target="_blank">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="" target="_blank">ACCOUNT</a></li>
            <li><a href="" target="_blank">CART (0)</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <i class="fa fa-bars" onclick="showmenu()"></i>
  </nav>

    <div class="text-box">
        <h1>Smell Good and Look Good</h1>
        <p>We believe that PTK Clothing can give you the best clothing you can wear!</p>
        <a href="home.html" target="_blank" class="hero-btn">Shop Shirts</a>
        <a href="home.html" target="_blank" class="hero-btn">Shop Traditional Wear</a>
    </div>
</section>

  <!---------- Logo and Search Panel HTML Code Ends --------->

    <!------ featured products ------>
  <div class="small-container">
    <h2 class="title">Shirts</h2>   
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-3">
        <img src="tee1.png" width="100">
        <h4>"THE SCENT YOU CAN'T SMELL" - BLACK</h4>
        <div class="rating">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i>
          <i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i>
          <i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i>
          <i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i>
          <i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i>
        </div>
      </div>   
      <div class="col-3">
        <img src="tee2.png" width="100">
        <h4>"NEVER ENDING FRAGRANCE" - BROWN</h4>
        <div class="rating">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i>
          <i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i>
          <i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i>
          <i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i>
          <i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-3">
        <img src="tee3.jpg" width="100">
        <h4>PTK STREETWEAR - BLACK</h4>
        <div class="rating">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i>
          <i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i>
          <i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i>
          <i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i>
          <i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-3">
        <img src="tee4.jpg" width="100">
        <h4>"FRAGRANCE" - WHITE</h4>
        <div class="rating">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i>
          <i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i>
          <i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i>
          <i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i>
          <i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!------ featured products ------>

    <section class="course">
      <h1>Products We Sell On Our Website</h1>
      <p>Displayed here are the products we sell to our Customers!</p>
  
      <div class="row">
          <div class="course-col">
              <h3>Sports Equipments</h3>
              <p> 
                  Sports equipment encompasses a wide range of specialized gear tailored to enhance athletic performance and safety. 
                  Each piece serves a crucial role in facilitating the practice and enjoyment of various sports. 
                  Innovations in design and technology continually evolve to meet the evolving needs and demands of athletes across different disciplines.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="course-col">
              <h3>Sports Wear</h3>
              <p> 
                  Sports wear refers to clothing specifically designed to optimize performance and comfort during physical activity. 
                  Engineered with moisture-wicking fabrics, breathable materials, and ergonomic designs, sports wear allows athletes to move freely while staying dry and comfortable. 
                  From compression garments to specialized footwear, sports wear plays a crucial role in enhancing mobility, reducing fatigue, and preventing injuries during workouts and competitions.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="course-col">
              <h3>Our Own Merchandise</h3>
              <p> Our own merchandise represents an extension of our brand identity, embodying our values, style, and message. 
                      Crafted with meticulous attention to detail and quality, each item serves as a tangible representation of our commitment to excellence.
                      By offering our own merchandise, we aim to deepen connections with our audience, foster brand loyalty, and create memorable experiences for our customers.</p>
          </div>
      </div>
      </div>

  <!-- Footer-Section HTML Code STARTS -->
<div class="width-100 margin-top-50 footer">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="width-25">
        <h2 class="quicklink-heading">Account Detail</h2>
        <ul class="quicklink-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Search</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Cart</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Checkout</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="width-25">
        <h2 class="quicklink-heading">Quick Link</h2>
        <ul class="quicklink-menu">
          <li><a href="#">My Profile</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Change Password</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Order History</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">My Whislist</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">My Cashback</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="width-25">
        <h2 class="quicklink-heading">Quick Link</h2>
        <ul class="quicklink-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Faq</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Download App</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Refer & Earn Cashback</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="width-25">
        <h2 class="quicklink-heading">GET IN TOUCH</h2>
        <ul class="get-in-touch">
          <li><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> E-MAIL:<a href="#" class="footer-e-mail"> wear@ptk.com</a></li>
          <li><i class="fa fa-headphones" aria-hidden="true"></i> WHATS-APP: +63 -1234 456 7890</li>
          <li><i class="fa fa-fax" aria-hidden="true"></i> CONTACT NO.: +63 -(123)-4567890</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="social-media">
          <li><a href="#"><img src="facebook.png"></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><img src="twitter.png"></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><img src="linkedin.png"></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><img src="instagram.png"></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!---------- Footer-Section HTML Code Ends --------->


  <!-----Javascript for Toggle Menu----->

  <script>

    var navLinks = document.getElementById("navLinks")
    function showmenu(){
        navLinks.style.right= "0";
    }
    function hidemenu(){
        navLinks.style.right = "-200px";
    }

  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is a pic if you can't run the code

[image]

This is what happens. Please someone help.

---

I already tried searching google and asking blackbox ai for answers but instead adds more errors to my code. I tried adding `<br>` after the blue blocks thinking that it will fix the problem, buti it still does not

Answer (score 1):

You are not properly closing some of your tags. For example `<section class="course">` is never closed, which puts the footer inside it.

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/ygzwtsn6/

I encourage you to check your footer in smaller screen resolutions since columns tends to overflow due to the combination of `display: table` and `float: left`. I recommend you to use `display: flex` instead for such layout.

Comment: Thank you for the advice!! It works and the footer does not crop anymore